# How to append JSON data to existing JSON file node.js

Tags: json, node.js, append, stringify

How to append an existing JSON file with comma "," as separator

```
anchors = [ {  "title":"  2.0 Wireless " }  ]
fs.appendFileSync('testOutput.json', JSON.stringify(anchors));
```

This current code's output is like this

```
[
   {
     "title":"  2.0 Wireless "
   }
 ]
 [
   {
     "title":"  Marshall Major II "
   }
]
```

How to I get this in the correct format with comma "," as separator

I want to get something like this

```
[
   {    
    "title":"  2.0 Wireless "
   },
   {
     "title":"  Marshall Major II "
   }
]
```

Comment: How about `require()`ing the file, adjusting the JavaScript object structure and writing it to the file again? Note: Even if there would be a `,` between the two arrays in your first example, it wouldn't be valid JSON. Keeping something valid JSON by just appending stuff is not really possible

Comment: I don’t think it would be valid JSON. You could create an array of arrays or an object containing a few arrays.

Comment: If you will append to the file a lot, csv might be a better choice than JSON. With JSON you have to read the whole file every time you edit it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this. Don't forget to define `anchors` array.

```
var data = fs.readFileSync('testOutput.json');
var json = JSON.parse(data);
json.push(...anchors);

fs.writeFile("testOutput.json", JSON.stringify(json))
```

Comment: This almost works my out put looks like this [
   {    
    "title":"  2.0 Wireless "
   },
   [{
     "title":"  Marshall Major II "
   }]
]

Answer (score 0):

I created two small functions to handle the data to append.

1. the first function will: read data and convert JSON-string to JSON-array
2. then we add the new data to the JSON-array
3. we convert JSON-array to JSON-string and write it to the file

example: you want to add data **{  "title":"  2.0 Wireless " }** to file **my_data.json** on the same folder root. just call **append_data (file_path , data )**  ,

it will append data in the JSON file, if the file existed . or it will create the file and add the data to it.

```
data = {  "title":"  2.0 Wireless " }
file_path = './my_data.json'
append_data (file_path , data )
```

---

the full code is here :

```
   const fs = require('fs');
   data = {  "title":"  2.0 Wireless " }
   file_path = './my_data.json'
   append_data (file_path , data )

   async function append_data (filename , data ) {

    if (fs.existsSync(filename)) {
        read_data = await readFile(filename)
        if (read_data == false) {
            console.log('not able to read file')
        }
        else {
            read_data.push(data)
            dataWrittenStatus = await writeFile(filename, read_data)
            if dataWrittenStatus == true {
              console.log('data added successfully')
            }
           else{
              console.log('data adding failed')
            }
        }
      else{
          dataWrittenStatus = await writeFile(filename, [data])
          if dataWrittenStatus == true {
              console.log('data added successfully')
          }
          else{
             console.log('data adding failed')
           }
      }
   }



    async function readFile  (filePath) {
      try {
        const data = await fs.promises.readFile(filePath, 'utf8')
        return JSON.parse(data)
      }
     catch(err) {
         return false;
      }
    }

    async function writeFile  (filename ,writedata) {
      try {
          await fs.promises.writeFile(filename, JSON.stringify(writedata,null, 4), 'utf8');
          return true
      }
      catch(err) {
          return false
      }
    }
```